# How to mock functions/methods which updates same object?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have 2 methods inside class

1. methodA()
2. methodB()

Code:

```
const myModule1 =  require('./foo');
const myModule2 =  require('./bar');

const obj = {
   value: 100,
   text: "Hello"
 };

const updatedObj = {
   value: 200,
   text: "Hello"
}

// Inside beforeEach block
myModule.methodA.mockReturnValue(() => obj);
myModule2.methodB.mockReturnValue(() => updatedObj);
```

Now methodA is returning mock object but the class which I am testing is using methodB and methodA both. Now methodB is updating same mock object which methodA returns and updates obj.value to 200 from 100.

Below expect code is meaningless if I use updatedObj because in that case what is the point of testing.
`expect(updatedObj.value).toEqual(200)` ---> No point in testing like this

How can I do something like this:
`expect(obj.value).toEqual(200)` assuming I am mocking return value of methodB which updates same object which returns same mocked obj. How can I achieve this?

So basically I want to mock methodA and methodB both but how to use same object instead of using two different is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you're testing either `methodA` or `methodB` alone you wouldn't mock them. If `methodA` uses `methodB` and you're testing `methodA` you wouldn't mock `methodA`. If you're testing `methodC` that uses `methodA` and `methodB`, but `methodB` relies on the results of `methodA` you wouldn't mock `methodB` because you'd be duplicating logic, and would run the risk of getting out of sync. This is one of the dangers of relying on side effects, especially *nested* side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is flawed. You do not test mocked objects. You assume that these work as intended. You want to test the code that uses those objects.

The things you do with mocks are:

1. check the result of the function that uses the mock object (i.e. do not consider the mock state, just provide mocks that return the correct value for that specific example)
2. You can *verify the calls*, so you can be sure that the calls to `methodA` were done with the correct **parameters**.

In other words you do not check that `obj.value` was mutated to `200`, you check that `methodA` was called with the correct parameters (such that the real implementation would have modified the object to set the parameter to 200).

You can [look at Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mock-return-values) that shows how to fetch the calls to the mock functions and so you'll have to make assertions about the *calls*, not the actions that the real implementation of the function would have performed.

So if `myModule.methodA` is a mock function you will check:

```
expect(myModule.methodA.mock.calls).toEqual([[200]])
```

This will test that the code made one call to `methodA` with a parameter of `200`.
Whether the real `methodA` would then have modified `obj` is an implementation detail that shouldn't really matter.

(You did not show the arguments of `methodA` or `B`, so obviously that will change depending on how it is called.

---

This said, be aware that *unit* testing try to isolate the different parts of the system, and to do this we use mocks. However it is also very useful to have *integration* tests. Basically just run `methodA` for real using in memory databases or webservers in place of the real stuff.

Basically checking that `obj` is changed with a value of `200` in this situation should be part of integration testing, not of the unit tests for the code that uses the mocked versions of `methodA/B`.